# error TS2307: Cannot find module 'class-validator' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, docker-compose, nestjs, class-validator

My nestjs app runs whenever I start it with `yarn start:dev`, but I get this error:

```
src/auth/dto/auth.dto.ts:1:35 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'class-validator' or its corresponding type declarations
```

Whenever I run `docker compose up` or `docker compose up --build`

My thought was that the `class-validator` module was not installed during my image build, so I tried rebuilding the image, but the error still persists.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /app-backend

COPY tsconfig*.json ./
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

CMD ["yarn", "start:dev"]
```

`dependencies` in `package.json`:

```
{
  "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
  "@nestjs/config": "^3.0.0",
  "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
  "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
  "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
  "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
  "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
  "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
  "typeorm": "^0.3.17"
}
```

Comment: check your `package.json` if it's there

Comment: It's in my package.json @Kaneki21

Comment: can you share your dockerfile and package.json

Comment: `FROM node:18

WORKDIR /app-backend

COPY tsconfig*.json ./

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

CMD ["yarn", "start:dev"]
`

my package.json:
`"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.17"
  }
`